# Make a dialog ignore default theme in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dialog, flutter-layout

I'm creating an app with Flutter. In my main.dart file I have specified a theme for dialogs like that:

```
theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Color(0xff2d2d2d),
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(primary: Color(0xffe2e2e2)),
          accentColor: Color(0xffe2e2e2),
          dialogTheme: DialogTheme(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xff2d2d2d),
            titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                fontSize: 16,
                color: Color(0xffe2e2e2)),
          ),
        )
```

Everything works fine but I have some pages in my app that have reversed colors. I placed a dropdown in one of them using a [searchable_dropdown](https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown) package, which creates a dialog with a list of countries but it takes all colors from this theme. Is there a way to make it ignore the default theme somehow and provide another one instead?

Here is the code for the dropdown:

```
SearchableDropdown.single(
          items: countries.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((country) {
            return (DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                child: Text(country['name']), value: country['name']));
          }).toList(),
          value: _country,
          searchHint: null,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _country = value;
            });
          },
          dialogBox: false,
          isExpanded: true,
          menuConstraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size.fromHeight(350))),
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, simply override default theme and pass whatever your custom theme in textstyle property.

```
Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith()
```